# SPARC arch: rosout node loads CPU on 100%

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosout, cpu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We experienced strange behaviour on our embedded SPARC-like system. Just after start, the `rosout` process loads CPU on 100%. We would be very appreciated if you guys help us to reveal the reason of such behaviour.

Also, how many processes should `roscore` run?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318372/sparc-arch:-rosout-node-loads-cpu-on-100%/) by [twdragon](https://answers.ros.org/users/40258/twdragon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-03-13**:
I've seen that happen when you abuse the parameter server, its meant for static parameters at bringup not to set throughout use (if you do that)

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2019-03-14**:
Probably won't solve your problem, but you can reduce the work done by rosout node in a [few ways](https://wiki.ros.org/rosout#rosout.log): disable topics in log lines, disable file logging.

NB: ROSOUT_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING is not yet in official melodic release, but there are other ways of disabling rosout file logging.

**Comment by [942951641@qq.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/38911/942951641@qq.com/) on 2019-05-21**:
I also meet this problem, rosout loads one full cpu kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some attempts to reveal the source of problem I found a solution. There are no correct realizations of `SteadyTimer` system entity on some VLIW and SPARC-like platforms. This leads any function using `SteadyTimer` to return immediately after calling. In threaded implementation such funсtions consume all CPU time just for continuous function calls. This issue can be solved with replacement of all SteadyTimer-related calls to equivalents which use `WallTimer`.

There is brilliant solution on GitHub made by Christopher Wecht: https://github.com/cwecht/ros_comm/tree/fix_subscription_busy_wait-melodic His solution makes ROS core true platform-independent on the described case.

To integrate Christopher's solution into the existing ROS sources it is only needed to replace `src/ros_comm/roscpp` directory with variant from [here](https://github.com/cwecht/ros_comm/tree/fix_subscription_busy_wait-melodic/clients). After that compiled ROS works properly on VLIW platforms.

---

Originally posted by [twdragon](https://answers.ros.org/users/40258/twdragon/) with karma: 28 on 2019-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-16**:\

> To integrate Christopher's solution into the existing ROS sources it is only needed to replace `src/ros_comm/roscpp` directory with variant from [here](https://github.com/cwecht/ros_comm/tree/fix_subscription_busy_wait-melodic/clients).

please be aware that you are now responsible for keeping `ros_comm` (and all pkgs in it) up-to-date. The fork you link to is (at the time of writing) 8 commits behind `melodic-devel`.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-05-16**:
It looks like there is a pull request to merge those changes into ros_comm: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1684 . At this time, it looks like there are still some open discussions that need to be resolved before it can merge.